# Replacing a word of an element with an empty string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have an element like:

```
<div class="title">Headquarters<br />
Warehouse</div>
```

I can't use CSS to hide a word within `.title` so I tried using jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('div.title')
    .html($('div.title').html().replace("Headquarters" + "<br />" + "Warehouse", "Test"));
});
```

But this isn't changing anything: http://jsfiddle.net/NAm66/

How can I hide the word "warehouse" within `.title` ?

Comment: What you are doing has nothing to do with hiding specific word. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @jQuerybeast: I want to remove the string "Warehouse" within the `.title` element.

Comment: @Stigma Do you want the <br /> tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace doesn't work that way `<br />` is an html element not a string.

With what you are doing just do:

```
$('div.title').empty();
```

or if you want to replace the content with something else then:

```
$('div.title').html("Test"); //or .text("Test")
```

Or just do:

```
$(function () {
    $('div.title').contents().each(function () {
        if(this.nodeType ===3 && this.nodeValue === "Warehouse"){
            this.nodeValue = '';
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Or

```
$(function () {
    $('div.title').contents().filter(function () {
        return this.nodeType === 3 && this.nodeValue === "Warehouse";
    }).remove();
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bwyht/)**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just **hide** the element I would suggest a super-tiny plugin I've hacked into in the past.

```
$.fn.cleartxt=function highlight(c){function e(b,c){var d=0;if(3==b.nodeType){var a=b.data.toUpperCase().indexOf(c);if(0<=a){d=document.createElement("span");d.className="inner";a=b.splitText(a);a.splitText(c.length);var f=a.cloneNode(!0);d.appendChild(f);a.parentNode.replaceChild(d,a);d=1;}}else if(1==b.nodeType&&b.childNodes&&!/(script|style)/i.test(b.tagName))for(a=0;a<b.childNodes.length;++a)a+=e(b.childNodes[a],c);return d}return this.length&&c&&c.length?this.each(function(){e(this,c.toUpperCase())}): this};
```

Then, simply call the body - or any element - and the desired word to be hidden.

As such:

```
$('body').cleartxt("Warehouse")
```

Finally, because of what the plugin does to hide the text, it wraps it around a span with class .inner - as you stated. Thus we need to apply visibility:hidden on .inner:

```
.inner{visibility:hidden}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/javascript/dps4c/

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$(function() {
$('div.title').html($('div.title').html().replace("Warehouse","Test"));
 });
```